# username is appearing as root instead of a user who logged in?

Tags: linux, centos

I have a CentOS server where i am logging in as a user **jenkins** but user name is appearing as **root** instead of **jenkins**

```
[root@centos-7-1 ~]# sudo su - jenkins  
Last login: Sat Jul 14 20:21:16 UTC 2018 on pts/0
[root@centos-7-1 ~]# hostname  
centos-7-1
```

I checked the sudoers file i found this, i am not sure if it is somehow related to the problem

```
[root@centos-7-1 etc]# cat group | grep jenkins
jenkins:x:993:

[root@centos-7-1 ~]# grep jenkins /etc/passwd 
jenkins:x:996:993:Jenkins Automation Server:/var/lib/jenkins:/bin/false
[root@centos-7-1 ~]#
```

When I execute `whoami` after switching users I get:

```
[root@centos-7-1 ~]# su - jenkins 
Last login: Sat Jul 14 20:33:18 UTC 2018 on pts/0 
[root@centos-7-1 ~]# whoami 
root
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, this is simple. Your `jenkins` user is defined in `/etc/passwd` like this:

```
jenkins:x:996:993:Jenkins Automation Server:/var/lib/jenkins:/bin/false
```

See that last entry, which says `/bin/false`? There isn't a valid shell defined for the jenkins user, so the session immediately terminates — and you're returned back to the root shell you started with.

Comment: Not asking for a login shell would solve that. Changing the login shell would be the worse option.

Comment: Thanks @mattdm

I edited the _/etc/passwd_ and replaced  _/bin/false_ with _/bin/bash_ solved the problem.  

Now it looks like this  

'[root@centos-7-1 ~]# su - jenkins`  
`Last login: Sat Jul 14 20:39:50 UTC 2018 on pts/0`  
`-bash-4.2$ whoami`
`jenkins`
-bash-4.2$ grep jenkins /etc/passwd
`jenkins:x:996:993:Jenkins Automation Server:/var/lib/jenkins:/bin/bash
-bash-4.2$ `

Comment: @Kusalananda Hmmm; not so in my testing. It still defaults to trying to start `/bin/false` as the shell, unless you give the `-s` option.

Comment: @Sourabh Changing the login shell _is a really bad thing to do_. Having `false` as the login shell is a security measure.

Answer (score 0):

`/bin/false` as the user's login shell stops the user from logging in on the system by normal means.  You don't want to change this as it's a security measure.  Just ask for another shell when switching to the target user:

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins
```

That is if your *really* need to use an interactive shell session as the `jenkins` user.  Since the user has no real login shell, it seems as if *you're not actually supposed to use this user interactively* during normal operation.